# How to populate days combobox based on month and year?

Tags: java, swing, date, netbeans, combobox

```
private void buildMonthsList(cmbMonth monthsList) {
    for (int monthCount = 0; monthCount < 12; monthCount++)
        monthsList.addItem(Const.MONTHS[monthCount]);
}

public boolean DaysComboBox (int year)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int months = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    year = (int) cmbYear.getSelectedItem();
    boolean leap = false;

    if(year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if( year % 100 == 0)
        {
            // year is divisible by 400, hence the year is a leap year
            if ( year % 400 == 0)
            {
                leap = true;
            }
            else {
                leap = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            leap = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        leap = false;
    }

    return leap;
}
```

I need some help with a Java Swing program I have for school which is important.

How can you fill in the number of days according to the month and year including leap year? I used 3 separate combo boxes, one for the days, another one for the months and another for the years. It should also be called from a method.

Comment: what are you using JavaFX, swing, JSF? put some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I am using Swing.

Comment: Jose, I edited my question now. It is so messy but im new to this and i couldnt find anything like how i want.

Comment: No need to invent your own `Const.MONTHS`, as we have the [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum.  Example:  `for ( Month month : Month.values() ) {
            System.out.println( month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) );  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, whatever.
        }` ⇒ janvier
février
mars
avril
mai
juin
juillet
août
septembre
octobre
novembre
décembre. See also `EnumSet` & `EnumMap`.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly i have to use those in my school soo 

Answer (score 4):

The "best" solution is take advantage of the available functionality.

Java 8+ introduced the `java.time` API, which replaces the `Calendar` and `Date` based APIs

For example, something like this, using [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class…

```
for (int year = 2010; year <= 2020; year++) {
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(year, Month.FEBRUARY);
    System.out.println(year + " = " + ym.lengthOfMonth());
}
```

will print...

```
2010 = 28
2011 = 28
2012 = 29
2013 = 28
2014 = 28
2015 = 28
2016 = 29
2017 = 28
2018 = 28
2019 = 28
2020 = 29
```

From this, you can simply create a new `ComboBoxModel`, fill it with the values you need and apply it to the instance of `JComboBox` - see [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details.