# How to disable items from Combo Box?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

How can I disable the items from the swing combo box? 
I added the items as code since in my project we cannot add them manually from the design. I want to disable items, such as if April is selected from the swing Month combo box, Item 31 should be disabled with a warning message too since the Month April has 30 days and not 31 days.

```
public void months()
```

{

```
   cmbDay.addItem("1");
   cmbDay.addItem("2");
   cmbDay.addItem("3");
   cmbDay.addItem("4");
   cmbDay.addItem("5");
   cmbDay.addItem("6");
   cmbDay.addItem("7");
   cmbDay.addItem("8");
   cmbDay.addItem("9");
   cmbDay.addItem("10");
   cmbDay.addItem("11");
   cmbDay.addItem("12");
   cmbDay.addItem("13");
   cmbDay.addItem("14");
   cmbDay.addItem("15");
   cmbDay.addItem("16");
   cmbDay.addItem("17");
   cmbDay.addItem("18");
   cmbDay.addItem("19");
   cmbDay.addItem("20");
   cmbDay.addItem("21");
   cmbDay.addItem("22");
   cmbDay.addItem("23");
   cmbDay.addItem("24");
   cmbDay.addItem("25");
   cmbDay.addItem("26");
   cmbDay.addItem("27");
   cmbDay.addItem("28");
   cmbDay.addItem("29");
   cmbDay.addItem("30");
   cmbDay.addItem("31");




   String getMonths = String.valueOf(cmbMonth.getSelectedItem());

  if (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("April"))
   {



   }

   else if (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("June"))
   {



   }
   else if (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("September"))
   {



   }
   else if (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("November"))
   {



   }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable certain items in a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722706/how-to-disable-certain-items-in-a-jcombobox)

Comment: `I added the items as code` - then only add the days that are valid for the month. This will be much simpler than trying to manipulate the UI into support disabled items. Also, why would you write 31 statements to add each item manually? Create a loop and add each item depending on the days in the month. You were given an example on how to do this in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936642/how-to-populate-days-combobox-based-on-month-and-year

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked, there are different aspects to disabling a particular item in a JComboBox's pull-down:

1. doing nothing when the user chooses a disabled item
2. making the item *appear* disabled (grey text instead of black text, for example)
3. making the item *behave* disabled (so that clicking on it doesn't dismiss the pull-down)

Aspect #1 isn't really a Swing issue but would be done in your event-handling code, and IMHO should be done even if #3 were implemented (even though #3 would seem to make #1 unnecessary).

Aspect #2 could be implemented by using a custom ListCellRendererfor your JComboBox. This isn't as hard as it sounds, except that there are a lot of code examples on the web that don't do it correctly. If you're new at it, it's hard to know which code examples to trust. (The same custom ListCellRenderer could also make a disabled item not appear to be decorated when the user holds the cursor over it.)

Aspect #3 is tricky. I'm not saying it's impossible, but (unless there's some relevant API I'm unaware of) I wouldn't bother because it would take too much work and even then would likely be too kludgy. [edit: Overriding ComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem() to do nothing if its argument is disabled does most of what you need. That's not too kludgy, but with this alone clicking on a disabled item will still dismiss the pop-up.]

But to answer a question that you didn't ask, is this really the best design? Do you really want users to see a pull-down list of options that includes some disabled items, rather than seeing a pull-down list that contains only the items that are valid? JComboBox provides a mechanism that can be used to adjust the items in the pull-down list just before the pull-down list pops up, which is addPopupMenuListener(). You would write your own PopupMenuListener and add or remove items in its popupMenuWillBecomeVisible() method.

Finally, consider how people might use your GUI. Let's say the combo boxes currently read February 1 and the user wants to change it to January 31. Do you want to force the user to change the month first, then the day? Or might the user try to change the day first (which would frustrate him/her because the 31 would be either disabled or absent) and then change the month? A reasonable design might be to allow the user to set the GUI to February 31, but only transitionally and simply not allow the GUI progressing to the next step if the date is incorrect.

Comment: this is just a GUI for a school project and i have to do that way unfortunatly

Comment: else if (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("November"))
       {
           
          cmbDay.removeItem("31");
           
       }  I Tried doing it this way but its not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying in the previous comment. Did you write a PopupMenuListener and try removing items in its popupMenuWillBecomeVisible() method? Or are you doing something else?